# How to verify client side partitioning with Predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

I am attempting to use client side partitioning via Predis.  Everything seems to be working, but how can I verify values are being stored on multiple servers?  I'd like to be able to list all keys on each server, but don't see how to in the predis documentation.  I'm try to do a simple info call but get exception errors:

`$predisClient->info()` generates an "Cannot use 'INFO' over clusters of connections" exception.  (This does work when using one server.)

`$predisClient->executeRaw( ['CLUSTER INFO'] )` generates an "Cannot use 'CLUSTER INFO' over clusters of connections" exception.

My `$predisClient` is defined as follows:

`$predisClient = new Predis\Client(['tcp:://127.0.0.1', 'tcp://<REMOTE SERVER IP HERE>']);`

I'm using redis 3.0.7, and predis 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered that you are using Predis v1.1 you can simply do:

```
foreach ($client as $node) {
    $info = $node->info('keyspace');
    // ...
}
```

This will work with both redis-cluster and a client-side sharded cluster. Please note that you configured the client to use the latter but `CLUSTER INFO` is only supported by redis-cluster (you'd need to direct this command to a specific node anyway since this command does not carry any key meaning that Predis has no way to calculate a slot).

When you want to list the keys stored on each node avoid `KEYS` (unless it's just for testing against a local setup) and prefer [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan). When using Predis, the [`Predis\Collection\Iterator\Keyspace`](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.1.1/examples/redis_collections_iterators.php#L43-L47) iterator abstracts `SCAN` so that you can simply use the standard `foreach` or `iterator_to_array()`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!  I didn't realize I could loop though the $client.

Fyi, because of the Predis session handler, I was able to migrate my apps from PHP 5.6 using memcached to PHP 7.x using redis.  Thank you for that too!